# Substring Occurrence in a String of Size $5$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

---

Question:

> How many strings can be formed by ordering the letters $ABCDE$ so that each string contains the substring $DB$ or the substring $BE$ or both?

---

Attempt:

There are four possible ways to order both the $(DB)$-substring and the $(BE)$-substring amongst the other three remaining; that is you have the following cases:
$$\overset{\text{Case 1}}{(DB)\star\star\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 2}}{\star(DB)\star\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 3}}{\star\star(DB)\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 4}}{\star\star\star(DB)}$$
The same goes for the $(BE)$-substring:
$$\overset{\text{Case 1}}{(BE)\star\star\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 2}}{\star(BE)\star\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 3}}{\star\star(BE)\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 4}}{\star\star\star(BE)}$$
Now, for the situation where both substrings are found we have that the substring $(DBE)$ is to be sought, namely we have the following cases:
$$\overset{\text{Case 1}}{(DBE)\star\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 2}}{\star(DBE)\star} ~~~~~~ \overset{\text{Case 3}}{\star\star(DBE)}$$
For both the $(DB)$-substrings and $(BE)$-substrings we have for each case a number of $1\cdot 3!=3\cdot 1 \cdot 2!=3\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1=3!\cdot 1=3!$ outcomes; that is, for the $(DB)$-substring we have $4\cdot 3!$ variations, and for the $(BE)$-substring we have $4\cdot 3!$ variations, so there is a total of $2\cdot 4\cdot 3!$ variations. Although, notice that we have counted too many, namely the $(DBE)$-substring occurences. Using the same logic from above, we see that the number of variations for the $(DBE)$-substring occurrences is $3\cdot 2!$. This needs to be subtracted from the total above:
$$2\cdot 4\cdot 3!-3\cdot 2!=42$$

---

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also correct, and here again you can also think of it a little differently. There are $4!$ ways to arrange the $4$ items consisting of a two-letter block and $3$ single letters, so there are $4!$ strings with $DB$ and $4!$ strings with $BE$. There are $3!$ ways to arrange the $3$ items consisting of the three-letter string $DBE$ and the remaining two single letters. Then apply the inclusion-exclusion argument that you used to get a total of $2\cdot4!-3!=48-6=42$ strings.